# The set St(k, n), k < n, is called the Stiefel set.

Tags: linear-algebra

The set St(k, n), k < n, is called the Stiefel set.

does matrix X= 
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
  0&-{\sqrt 2}/2 \\
  0&{\sqrt 2}/2\\
1&0
\end{array}
\right] $$

belong to St(2,3)?

Im not really sure how to solve this. I dont understand what a stiefel set is and i've tried reading about it, but i still dont get it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel_manifold), and [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StiefelManifold.html), a Stiefel manifold is a set of ordered $\ k$-tuples, $\ \left(v_1, v_2, \dots, v_k\right)\ $, of orthonormal vectors in $\ \mathbb{R}^n\ $.  Presumably, this is what your expression $\ \text{St}(k,n)\ $ is intended to represent.

So if you treat your matrix $\ X\ $ as an ordered set of columns, then it will lie in $\ \text{St}(2,3)\ $ if and only it's an ordered set of $\ 2\ $ orthonormal columns in $\ \mathbb{R}^3\ $.  Can you see whether or not that's true?

Comment: could you explain more please?